# What useful information can be efficiently extracted from solutions provided by the HHL-algorithm?

Tags: hhl-algorithm

The result of the HHL-algorithm is the (amplitude-encoded) solution vector $|x\rangle$.

I was wondering, which useful information could be extracted from this solution without loosing the algorithms speedup by sampling it $O(N)$ times.

What I found is:

- [Calculate the absolute average](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21924/which-observable-m-provides-the-absolute-average-of-a-statevector)
- [Calculate overlap with a given vector](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/hhl-and-choice-of-observable-for-calculating-the-expectation-value-thereof)

However, if I understand the answer to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/is-there-a-quantum-algorithm-allowing-to-efficiently-determine-the-state-with-th) correctly, it should also not be possible to find the largest values efficiently.

Can you give more examples ? (Specifically I am interested in a method to efficiently determine if there are components $x_i$ of $x$ that exceed a certain limit)